# Java class to call a SOAP - Web service

Tags: java, web-services, class, soap

I have a SOAP that i need to call from Oracle and i have heard that the only way to work it out is through a Java class , Unfortunately im not familiar with Java as i'm an Oracle developer ( Oracle Forms ) I really appreciated it if someone can help me creating a class calling this SOAP so that i can build it on my Oracle database and call it from Oracle forms builder the way i call a function .

There are two SOAPs (1.1 nd 1.2 ) , both of any can work :

***** SOAP 1.1

The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

```
POST /gmgwebservice/service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 212.35.66.180
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/SendSMS"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <SendSMS xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <UserName>string</UserName>
      <Password>string</Password>
      <MessageBody>string</MessageBody>
      <Sender>string</Sender>
      <Destination>string</Destination>
    </SendSMS>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <SendSMSResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <SendSMSResult>string</SendSMSResult>
    </SendSMSResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

******SOAP 1.2

The following is a sample SOAP 1.2 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

```
POST /gmgwebservice/service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 212.35.66.180
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <SendSMS xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <UserName>string</UserName>
      <Password>string</Password>
      <MessageBody>string</MessageBody>
      <Sender>string</Sender>
      <Destination>string</Destination>
    </SendSMS>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <SendSMSResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <SendSMSResult>string</SendSMSResult>
    </SendSMSResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Comment: If you have to call a Web Service it's not mandatory to use Java, you could use another langage. Anyway if you have to use Java I would recommend using the CXF framework for this purpose (see http://cxf.apache.org/).

Comment: I don't know how Oracle Forms works so maybe my question is stupid. Anyway, is it possible to develop Java code with Oracle Forms, I mean is it possible to have a real Java project? If it is possible then CXF is the solution IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

To implement simple SOAP clients in Java, you can use the SAAJ framework (it is shipped with JSE 1.6 and above):

> **SOAP with Attachments API for Java (SAAJ)** is mainly used for dealing directly with SOAP Request/Response messages which happens behind the scenes in any Web Service API. It allows the developers to directly send and receive soap messages instead of using JAX-WS.

See below a working example (run it!) of a SOAP web service call using SAAJ. It calls [this web service](http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx?wsdl).

```
import javax.xml.soap.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

public class SOAPClientSAAJ {

    /**
     * Starting point for the SAAJ - SOAP Client Testing
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            // Create SOAP Connection
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

            // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
            String url = "http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx";
            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

            // Process the SOAP Response
            printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);

            soapConnection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        String serverURI = "http://ws.cdyne.com/";

        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("example", serverURI);

        /*
        Constructed SOAP Request Message:
        <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:example="http://ws.cdyne.com/">
            <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
            <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                <example:VerifyEmail>
                    <example:email>mutantninja@gmail.com</example:email>
                    <example:LicenseKey>123</example:LicenseKey>
                </example:VerifyEmail>
            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
         */

        // SOAP Body
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("VerifyEmail", "example");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("email", "example");
        soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("mutantninja@gmail.com");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("LicenseKey", "example");
        soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("123");

        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI  + "VerifyEmail");

        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        /* Print the request message */
        System.out.print("Request SOAP Message = ");
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();

        return soapMessage;
    }

    /**
     * Method used to print the SOAP Response
     */
    private static void printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
        System.out.print("\nResponse SOAP Message = ");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
    }

}
```

(The code above was taken and adapted from [this page](http://techdive.in/web-service/saaj-web-service-soap-client).)

Answer (score 0):

You can call SOAP methods from a variety of programming languages.  If you need to do it within Java, you will want to look into [JAX-WS](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/).  [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/webservices-forms-11g-094111.html) is a tutorial for using JAX-WS with Oracle Forms Builder.  To use it you will need Forms Builder 11g.

You provide the wizard with the URL of the WSDL (web services description language) file.  It walks you through the Java code you need to send a message to the SOAP service, deployment, and code import.